# How to pass parameters in scheduling a windows task(WinXP) in C++?

Tags: c++, parameters, task, scheduler

I am writing code to schedule a Windows task (an C++ program .dll) using code from MSDN [Time Trigger example](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/taskschd/time-trigger-example--c---?redirectedfrom=MSDN). I can not figure out how to pass a command line parameter to my .dll, in the example, only exe file path present like below,

```
wstring wstrExecutablePath = _wgetenv( L"WINDIR");
wstrExecutablePath += L"\\SYSTEM32\\NOTEPAD.EXE";
```

but for running this dll file, the full command  shall be `rundll32.exe "c:\\test.dll" parameter` for XP

so i cannot achieve it with Microsoft example, there is no way to pass parameters to .

please give me some advice, thanks in advance.